# How do I override Jquery Mobile Structure CSS with customThemeRoller CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

**edit**: I just realized the classes I was trying to have styled are NOT included in the ThemeRollers CSS.  I was trying to style `.ui-li` elements, but these are not included in ThemeRoller.  Very misleading and aggravating.  I don't recall this ever being addressed on their website.

I have made my first custom theme through JQM's ThemeRoller.  The JQM structure CSS that is to be included keeps overriding my custom ThemeRoller CSS. I've tried placing it in the `<head>` section of the HTML code above and below the JQM structure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCustomTheme.css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCustomTheme.css" />
```

I've also tried the `!important` thing in the custom CSS for the elements that have the incorrect style, but this still is overridden by the structure CSS.  Not sure why this is so.  How can I use my custom ThemeRoller css so that it overrides the unthemed JQM Structure CSS?

Comment: have your theme after the mobile theme and your styles will over write the mobile once if there is the same class or ID used. Also using `!important` is more of a visual aid for yourself with the CSS so you dont delete that part of the CSS

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Andrew.  In my HTML, I have my Custom Theme after the JQM theme and the JQM still overwrites mine.

Comment: @user2132703 With just a link that leads to some stylesheet it's very difficult (_...if not impossible..._) to help you. Is it the linking itself? Is it an error in the way your styles are written? We can only assume... Can you show us some code please?

Answer (score 2):

- Seeing the clarification in your question.Have you tried giving `data-role="none"` with the elements you want to give the customized css?
- It will prevent those element from getting applied the jquery mobile structure css.
- And also you are always allowed to edit the jquery mobile css to your customized styling. We need to use unminified version of jquery mobile css for debugging purpose.